# Convert value at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, converters, unity-container, prism

I have a trivial problem but simply cannot figure out a **proper** way how to deal with it.

I have two simple models:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public Address EmployeeAddress { get; set; }

    //hierachy level
    public int EmployeeLevelID { get; set; }
}
```

and the other model:

```
public class EmployeeLevel
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int LevelID { get; set; }
}
```

By `EmployeeLevel` I mean that `LevelID` 1 would have `DisplayName` **Manager** and `LevelID` 2 would be e.g. **Regular Employee**

As you can see, I am storing simple `int` value of `EmployeeLevelID`, which determines who the current `Employee` is. The reason why it is like that, is that Users can determine themselves what are the `DisplayNames` for their positions, that's the reason why they are separated in two different models.

What I need to do, is when displaying current Employee's info on the page/form, I want to show `DisplayName` of his position, rather than `LevelID`.

The problem is, that the list of all the positions with their ID's are stored under my `EmployeeRepository` (I am using `Unity` & `Prism` in my project) and even if I built a `IValueConverter`, I won't be able to pass the collection that easily.

I could surely create a separate layer, which would serve as a holder of public values (visible by all classes), but I don't believe that it is the way to go.

Any suggestions (even regarding my models) would be more than appreciated as I am quite stuck at the moment.

Comment: In that case, don't you consider to put your `EmployeeLevel` as a property of `Employee`?

Comment: How would I keep track of the employee levels when adding new Employee? What I mean is, that if user decides to e.g. rename `LevelID` 1 from **Manager** to **CEO**, then all the other **Managers** would have the old value assigned (change to CEO would not be automatic)....no?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. If each `Employee` has its own `EmployeedLevel`, why would that affect the other Manager and CEO?

Comment: `List<EmployeeLevel>` is shared among all employees. Small team consists of Manager, Programmer & Tester. Those are 3 different EmployeeLevels. This way, when we are adding new team member, we can simply pick from the three already existing positions, rather than re-defining position for every single employee

Comment: OK, you shared a list... thanks for the clarification...

Answer (score 1):

A member class would not be a great data structure for this case because you do not want to store the display name in every employee, it's a waste of space, and if you had to change the display name you would have to iterate through all the employees that have that levelID.

We can simply use an array of strings for this matter, the ID would be the index and the display name would be the value,we can even make this array a static member of the class, so that it is easily accessible by any objects.

```
public class Employee
{
static int[] DisplayNameList = new int[] { "Manager", "Regular Employee", "Intern" };

// rest of the member variables

public int EmployeeLevelID { get; set; }
}
```

You access the list by using the ID as the index.

```
Employee.DisplayNameList[EmployeeLevelID];
```

Now you can just change a display name by modifying a value in the static array.

```
Employee.DisplayNameList[0] = "CEO";
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not quite understand this schema. Could you show me (easy example) how to implement it in my MVVM schema, please?

Comment: @RobertJ. I edited the answer to be a bit clearer.

The first piece of code would be the schema. Add in the rest of the code between both statements.

However you choose to display the contents of the Employees is irrelevant, (through an UI, through the console) 
The second piece o code shows how you can access the display name of an employee given an integer

Finally the third piece of code shows how to change the value of a display name.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a separate view model, and store the string in there instead of the int. Then, all you'd have to do is map your base model to the view model and pass the view model to the view.

```
public class EmployeeViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Address EmployeeAddress { get; set; }
    public String EmployeeLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var employeeViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel {
    Name = employee.Name,
    Surname = emplployee.Surname,
    DateOfBirth = employee.DateOfBirth,
    EmployeeAddress = employee.EmployeeAddress,
    EmployeeLevel = employeeLevels
                      .First(l => l.LevelId == employee.EmployeeLevelId)
                      .Select(l => l.DisplayName)
}
```

Of course you could simplify the process by using something like AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I decided to solve the problem (I am still open to any suggestion though).

Under my ViewModel I am loading `EmployeeLevels` in the constructor and setting it as public

```
    public ObservableCollection<EmployeeLevel> EmployeeLevels { get; set; }
```

Afterwards, I have created `IMultiValueConverter` which looks like following:

```
public class PositionLevelConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values == System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || values.Length != 2)
            return string.Empty;


        var collection = values[1] as ObservableCollection<EmployeeLevel>;

        if (collection == null)
            return string.Empty;

        return collection.FirstOrDefault(n => n.LevelID == (int)values[0])?.DisplayName;

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and finally, under my View, my item looks like this (this is a DataGrid control, which displays items in a table-like format):

```
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Position">
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PositionConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="EmployeeLevelID"/>
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}" Path="DataContext.EmployeeLevels"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```